# CB 1.9.1 List Manager alternative list manager plugins

Tags: component, joomla-2.5, plugin, module

I'm using Community Builder (CB) 1.9.1 on Joomla 2.5.20 and find the CB List manager wanting. My intention is to stay with CB especially since 2.0 is on the horizon, but in the meantime,I've been looking for alternative extensions or plugins. Being able to control column widths, concatenate fields, bold and vary font sizes of labels etc are the specific shortcomings that come to mind. Pretty basic stuff from my point of view.

A point to extension or plugin capabilities to enhance CB List Management is appreciated.

Comment: For most of those couldn't you use CSS?

Comment: @cppl I suppose, but I don't know CSS and the point of using a system like Joomla/CB is to operate and administer, not reprogram or rewrite custom modules.  CSS is, imho, a slippery slope.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something other than CB you should check out EasyProfile. They have recently developed a user community platform that looks to have great potential. I currently use their EasyProfile Pro user login profile which is great.

The developers have great response and support times, all the apps are very customisable too.

Maybe worth a look?

Comment: no, to me it is not worth shopping around for an entire replacement for CB, especially now when we stand only weeks or a few months from CB 2.0 which I understand is a big leap forward. But thanks anyway for the response.